# Table won't display in browser

Tags: html, html-table

I'm writing a code for the following table and it doesn't seem to display in the browser. I checked my code to see if there is some typo, and I can't find any.

Here's what the table has to look like:
[image]

And here's my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td rowspan=2></td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you put `&nbsp;` in the empty cells? Also, you might want a CSS style that sets the borders explicitly

Comment: Have you tried to use `&nbsp;` between your `<td>&nbsp;</td>` ?  Also, you may want to turn on Border=1 too.

Comment: I tried adding &nbsp; between each <td> tag as well, but it doesn't seem to show. After adding &nbsp; the only thing that changed is that I can see the table if I select it, else it's invisible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table is invisible until you add styling and data to it.

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table td {
   border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Without CSS but not recommended is to use the border attribute:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: We haven't studied CSS yet, so is there any other way instead of doing that?

Comment: Yes you can use the border attribute on the table

Comment: Thanks, it works after adding that line of code, however the table is extremely small, is there anything I can do to fix that as well?

Comment: for padding you can use <table border="1" cellpadding="30">

Comment: You can add data to your table. or like others have recommended you can add a non breaking space in it: `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML border, width and height attribute of the table:

```
<table border="1" width=500px height=500px>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td rowspan=2></td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is how we did this when we started learning HTML :)

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5XMf/1/)

Answer (score 2):

This works..  I just tested it..

```
<html>
<body>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```